# LiveData not updating on postValue()

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I have got the following UI for the search functionality.

```
 View (UI)   <<  ViewModel()  << LiveData(Remote)
(Search UI)      (Search VM)     Fetch data from remote
```

As said above, **View** observes a particular method in **ViewModel** which returns the LiveData as below:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    viewModel.finalLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, listChangeObserver)
}

// Observer responsible for updating the UI via adapter.
private val listChangeObserver: Observer<List<User>> = Observer { users ->
      users?.let { updateUI(it) } ?: run { updateUI(emptyList()) }
}

override fun onStop() {
    viewModel.finalLiveData.removeObserver(listChangeObserver)
    super.onStop()
}
```

while in the ViewModel, the `initSearch(searchKey:String)` filters the LiveData received from remote and prepares final one for the View as blow:

```
// Initiates the search with supplied search keys.
fun initSearch(searchInput: String?) {

    // filtering happens in Deserializer() class
    finalLiveData = Transformations.map(FirebaseQueryLiveData(query)) {
        repository.getSearchList(it, searchInput, searchLocation)
    }
}
```

and the `initSearch` will be called from view as `viewModel.initSearch(searchKey)`. Now, the issue is, the `finalLiveData` receives the value from tranformation but unfortunately the View is not updated.

But, noticed the data reflects in the View if users tries recent apps and comeback (by calling `onPause()` and `onResume()`)

Is there any better way to update the observed `LiveData`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed.

Solution posted below. by making finalLiveData as Mutable one and using a temporary LiveData, searchLiveData, to hold the result. As and when the searchLiveData gets updated the finalLiveData will get updated.

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/e9to2o/livedata_updates_are_not_reflecting_in_view/fant2x9?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

```
internal var finalLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<User>>()


fun initSearch(searchInput: String?) {
    val searchLiveData = Transformations.map(FirebaseQueryLiveData(query)) {
        repository.getSearchList(it)
    }

    (searchLiveData as LiveData<List<User>>).observeForever { users ->
        finalLiveData.value = users
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `userListRemote` the `LiveData` from your repo? It won't work without a `lifecycleowner`.

You can try to map directly to your `finalLiveData` instead of using the `temp`:

```
finalLiveData = Transformations.map(userListRemote, // do your mapping here)
```

In this way, `userListRemote` will use the `viewLifecycleOwner` of `finalLiveData`.

Comment: Thanks Yang. I tried assigning finalLiveData with the result of finalLiveData = Transformations.map(userListRemote, Deserializer()) as MutableLiveData<List<ProfessionalUser>> but the view is not updated. I suspect the View observer.

Comment: though the LiveData is updated with results, the view is not reflected with results. The View updated when went out(recent apps) and came back.

Comment: Sure, View and ViewModel interactions are shared above in question. Which other areas would be of your interest?